# Statement invalid when attempting to implement password_reset Railscast

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, passwords, password-recovery

I'm attempting to implement [Railscast #274](http://railscasts.com/episodes/274-remember-me-reset-password) in my app so I can provide a password reset option. I got to the point where I can type my email into a form for password resets and receive an email with a link to reset the password. Things start to go wrong when I enter my new password and attempt to save it. I ended up with an `Action Controller:Exception caught`. Here is what my log showed after I sent myself an email with the password_reset link:

```
Started GET "/password_resets/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-01-26 00:50:42 -0500
  Processing by PasswordResetsController#new as HTML
```

**Clicking the password_reset link:**

```
Started GET "/password_resets/qlslPnuOhdyMCNseMnV3bA/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-01-26 00:51:08 -0500
  Processing by PasswordResetsController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"qlslPnuOhdyMCNseMnV3bA"}
```

**Adding a new :password and :password_confirmation yields the error:**

```
Started POST "/password_resets/qlslPnuOhdyMCNseMnV3bA" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-01-26 00:53:08 -0500
  Processing by PasswordResetsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"2egfT2lr35FhuVPWDB72vcS2zPlqC75tcyctRp61ZHw=", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "commit"=>"Update Password", "id"=>"qlslPnuOhdyMCNseMnV3bA"}

Started GET "/profiles/qlslPnuOhdyMCNseMnV3bA" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-01-26 00:53:09 -0500
  Processing by ProfilesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"qlslPnuOhdyMCNseMnV3bA"}

  Profile Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."id" = 'qlslPnuOhdyMCNseMnV3bA' LIMIT 1
PGError: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "qlslPnuOhdyMCNseMnV3bA"
LINE 1: ...ofiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."id" = 'qlslPnuOh...
                                                             ^
: SELECT  "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."id" = 'qlslPnuOhdyMCNseMnV3bA' LIMIT 1
Completed   in 57ms

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PGError: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "qlslPnuOhdyMCNseMnV3bA"
LINE 1: ...ofiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."id" = 'qlslPnuOh...
                                                         ^
: SELECT  "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."id" = 'qlslPnuOhdyMCNseMnV3bA' LIMIT 1):
  app/controllers/profiles_controller.rb:41:in `show'
```

In profiles_controller.rb:41 in `show`:

```
def show
  @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
  @user = User.find(@profile.user_id)
  ..
end
```

Before doing this I dumped my database, ran `rake:db create`, then `rake:db migrate` before re-seeded the db. Could this be because I haven't run a script to give existing users a password_reset_token?

**UPDATE:** Including `password_resets_controller.rb`:

class PasswordResetsController < ApplicationController
      def new
      end

```
  def create
    @user = @User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    if user
      user.send_password_reset
      redirect_to new_password_reset_path, :notice => "Check your email for password reset instructions."
    else
      redirect_to new_password_reset_path, :notice => "Sorry, we couldn't find that email. Please try again."
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find_by_password_reset_token!(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find_by_password_reset_token!(params[:id])
    if @user.password_reset_sent_at < 2.hours.ago
      redirect_to new_password_reset_path, :alert => "Your password reset link has expired."
    elsif @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      redirect_to profile_path, :notice => "Great news: Your password has been reset."
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Updated with my controller code. I also added a second line to `profiles_controller.rb`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem is in your `PasswordResetsController#update`:

```
def update
  @user = User.find_by_password_reset_token!(params[:id])
  if @user.password_reset_sent_at < 2.hours.ago
    redirect_to new_password_reset_path, :alert => "Your password reset link has expired."
  elsif @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    redirect_to profile_path, :notice => "Great news: Your password has been reset."
  else
    render :edit
  end
end
```

The `redirect_to profile_path` in particular.

If you look at the logs, you'll see this sequence:

```
POST "/password_resets/qlslPnuOhdyMCNseMnV3bA"
GET  "/profiles/qlslPnuOhdyMCNseMnV3bA"
```

and the routes should be `/password_resets/:id` and `/profiles/:id`. The `/password_resets` wants the `'qlslPnuOhdyMCNseMnV3bA'` token but `/profiles` wants the user's numeric ID.

Going back to the controller we see this:

```
redirect_to profile_path, :notice => "Great news: Your password has been reset."
```

You don't tell `profile_path` which user to use so apparently it is grabbing `params[:id]` to build the incorrect `/profiles/qlslPnuOhdyMCNseMnV3bA` URL. Try telling `profile_path` which user to use with something like this:

```
redirect_to profile_path(@user), :notice => "Great news: Your password has been reset."
```

Comment: Thanks! That got me past my error but didn't update my User model. It redirected me to the logged_out version of my profile instead of logged_in.

Comment: @tvalent2: Try signing your user in before `redirect_to profile_path(@user)`. The original that you're working from expects them to sign in manually after resetting their password.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. Turns out I didn't have `attr_accessible :password, :password_confirmation` in my `User` model either. Not sure if that'll help...

Comment: That lack of `attr_accessible` could be blocking the `update_attributes`.

Comment: Well I'll give all this a go and see what happens. Thanks!